# How to add time diff of next time tuple in python

Tags: python

I was looking out something like 
1) capture the start_time = now 
2) and add time difference to achieve nearest tuple to complete the quarter of an hour

e.g some task is started @ 10:11:00 and code will add a timer to end time something 10:15:00
so we need to start timer on diff of 4 min

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your code, sample input, and expected output.

Comment: I am not able to start on this Input : Start a Task @ 10:10 or any time we need to identify the diff to achieve 10:15  another example  is a take started on 11:31 and it will completed to 11:45 basically 15 min tuple

Comment: @techysingh Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).